# kendo grid delete - confirmation window issues

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, crud, destroy, confirm

I have problem with confirmation popup during deleting item. When I click "Delete" confirmation window is popup-ing more times than one, and I don't know why. And second question is how I can change text of that window? I tried This code but don't work:

```
columns: [
   ...,
{command: [{name: "destroy", text: "Delete Item", click: deleteItem}],
 title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px"}
]
```

and function for delete:

```
function deleteItem(e) {
   var item = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
   if (confirm("delete item " + item.Name + " ?")) {
      var grid = $("grid").data("kendoGrid");
      grid.dataSource.remove(item);
      grid.dataSource.sync();
      grid.refresh();
   }
}
```

edited:
second problem which I found is, after click update button some items from grid are removed

Answer (score 0):

Check the following sample and let me know if it helps:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/custom-delete-confirmation-dialog

Comment: i'm forget for div with window id :) .. so delete works but i found issues with update ... after click update button some items are removed from grid or remove all items .. it's random

Comment: my code is here https://jsfiddle.net/brg2eraq/ ... but not work becouse my service is only local

Answer (score 0):

probably you must try using following code before every other in the delete handler

```
e.preventDefault()
```

This will prevent the execution of the default window and will provide space for the confirm to popup.Thus, allowing just one window in front of you
I hope this helps

Comment: If possible can you please elaborate your question by updating some more code or creating a JsFiddle?

Comment: hi, deleting items i repair with missing div for window ... but can you help me with second issues? After click Update button are remove one or more items from grid

Comment: my code is here https://jsfiddle.net/brg2eraq/ ... but not work becouse my service is only local

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate confirmation is due to you binding your command to the name "destroy" which is a [built-in command](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.destroy) provided by the grid. The command is firing, showing the built-in confirmation and then showing your confirmation. If you wish to handle the destroy method yourself simply rename the command to something other than "destroy" that is unique to you so that the default command event doesn't fire:

```
{command: [{name: "delete", text: "Delete Item", click: deleteItem}], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px"}
```

It appears you've got a few other issues in your deleteItem function as well. Try the following instead:

```
function deleteItem(e) {
   var item = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
   if (confirm("delete item " + item.Name + " ?")) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      grid.dataSource.remove(item);
      grid.dataSource.sync();
      grid.refresh();
   }
}
```

Notice I changed your code to use ***e.target*** rather than ***e.currentTarget*** and also modified your jQuery selector to look for ***#grid*** instead of ***grid*** assuming you're querying for an id and not a class.

See [this snippet](http://dojo.telerik.com/AKIhu) for a working example similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok, i repair code and try debug in browser, but i found this error 
https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2016/06/28/Zytu.png

maybe this is reason why i have trouble with window ... do you have idea why couldn't initialize item?